# I want to display data side by side on one sheet based on different filters

Tags: python, pandas, database

I created a big list of tables based on multiple conditions. Now I need to display data side by side using multiple filters.
I would like to know how to apply/combine multiple filter conditions on the table, so that it generates other views on the same script.

Here is the script

```
df = df[(df.category == 'Pant1') | (df.category == 'Pant2')]
def create_summary_tables (df):

white = df[df['color']=='White'].shape[0]
blue = df[df['color']=='Blue'].shape[0]
black = df[df['color']=='Black'].shape[0]
green = df[df['color']=='Green'].shape[0]

pant = pd.DataFrame([
    ['White', white, (round(((white/(df.shape[0]))*100),2))],
    ['Blue',  blue, (round((( blue/(df.shape[0]))*100),2))]],
    ['Black',  black, (round((( black/(df.shape[0]))*100),2))]],
    ['Green,  green, (round((( green/(df.shape[0]))*100),2))]],
    columns = ['Color', 'Sum', 'Percent'])
return(pant)
```

This is the output I want, and want to apply different filters highlighted at the top-
[image]

Comment: Dash datatable - check one of the tutorials. Or possibly itable, but found it a bit limiting

Comment: Can you please point me out to a specific tutorial? or if there is something you can suggest better.

Comment: maybe you should first create separated dataframes for different filters and later merge them - [Merge, join, concatenate and compare — pandas 1.4.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity - see options for filtering; assuming you want something interactive like your screenshot indicates.